# Custom Authorization in Spring

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-security, token

I'm writing a REST service that requires authorization through a third-party service. Currently I've got a `@RestController` on /auth path, with /login as the endpoint receiving the credentials. I've already managed to authenticate with the other service, and I'm getting authorization data from it, which I'd like to use as a token in authorization to other endpoints on my server.

I have been reading on Spring Security for token based authentication, but I could only find authorizations based on local user store or use the Basic Http authorization. I would prefer that the authorization data didn't leave the server, at least not in plaintext form. How can I achieve that?

Comment: So the other 3rd party service calls your "/auth/login" endpoint passing authentication data (in what way? HTTP Basic, Bearer token, just as query string params?). And what do you want to do with the authentication then? If you want to securely pass the credentials to other services called by your application then you may want to use JWT (see https://jwt.io/). Or are you trying to initiate an authenticated HTTP session in your server to allow the 3rd party service to call other endpoints without having to provide credentials with each API call?

Comment: actually I'm doing the calls to the 3rd party service, my service serves as a middle-man between the service consumer and the 3rd party service. The authentication in /auth/login is received via JSON object in POST body. After I authenticate I receive two variables, that I can use to authenticate all future requests to the 3rd party service, so I need to retain those and somehow bind them to the user.